# On proving the following function is entire

Tags: complex-analysis

I am asked to prove that the function $\exp\left(z^2\right)$ is entire. Now, I know that it can be proven via the Cauchy-Riemann equations, or even by stating that the given function is given by the composition of two entire functions ($z^2$ and $e^z$). However, I am wondering if the following way is also acceptable.

$$\begin{aligned}\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{e^{\left(z+h\right)^2}-e^{z^2}}{h}&=e^{z^2}\cdot\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{e^{h^2+2zh}-1}{h}\xrightarrow[]{\text{L'Hospital}}2ze^{z^2}\cdot\lim_{h\to 0}e^{h^2+2zh}=2ze^{z^2}.\end{aligned}$$
This solution seems much easier than using the C-R equations. Is this valid? Do I need to prove that this solution is continuous everywhere?
Thank you.

Comment: To use the Hospital, you need to know the function in question is differentiable, which is what you are trying to prove in the first place!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculation shows that $f(z):=\exp(z^2)$ is complex differentiable everywhere in the open set $\mathbb{C}$. Thus, $f$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}$. Finally, entire functions are precisely the functions which are holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}$.

The only possible issue here is the use of l'Hôpital's rule. If you are comfortable with it, you're alright.

Comment: What do you mean when you state  "the only possible issue here is the use of l'Hôpital's rule"? If I am differentiating with respect to $h$, then it is a simple differentiation in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @MathGuru $h$ is complex here. If you haven't seen the complex l'Hoôpital's rule, you should familiarize yourself with it first. That is (possibly) the only issue.